# Why does the function behave this way?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I wrote a function which collects binary tree into any type that belongs to `Monoid` type class using any type of traversal.

Type for tree is defined like this:

```hs
data BinTree a = EmptyBT |
                 NodeBT a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
                 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

And enum type for different kind of traversals:

```hs
data TravOrder = Inorder | Preorder | Postorder
```

My first attempt at writing the function:

```hs
collectBT :: Monoid m => TravOrder -> (a -> m) -> BinTree a -> m
collectBT Inorder = \f tree -> 
    case tree of
        EmptyBT -> mempty
        NodeBT val lt rt -> recursion lt <> f val <> recursion rt
            where recursion = collectBT Inorder f

collectBT Preorder = \f tree ->
    case tree of
        EmptyBT -> mempty
        NodeBT val lt rt -> f val <> recursion lt <> recursion rt
            where recursion = collectBT Preorder f

collectBT Postorder = \f tree ->
    case tree of
        EmptyBT -> mempty
        NodeBT val lt rt -> recursion lt <> recursion rt <> f val
            where recursion = collectBT Postorder f
```

This version worked correctly. Then I removed duplicate code:

```hs
combineInOrder :: Monoid m => TravOrder -> m -> m -> m -> m
combineInOrder Inorder = \val lt rt -> lt <> val <> rt
combineInOrder Preorder = \val lt rt -> val <> lt <> rt
combineInOrder Postorder = \val lt rt -> lt <> rt <> val

collectBT' :: Monoid m => TravOrder -> (a -> m) -> BinTree a -> m
collectBT' ord f EmptyBT = mempty
collectBT' ord f (NodeBT val rt lt) =
    let recursion = collectBT ord f 
    in combineInOrder ord (f val) (recursion lt) (recursion rt)
```

Now the function returns incorrect results. I think it should behave the same way because the `monoids` are combined in the same order. What am I missing ?

Expression generating simple tree in case someone wants to run it:

```hs
(NodeBT 1 (NodeBT 2 EmptyBT EmptyBT) (NodeBT 3 EmptyBT EmptyBT))

  1
 / \
2   3
```

Comment: you are calling `collectBT` (not `collectBT'`) in the `recursion`?

Comment: You write `NodeBT val rt lt` as your pattern. You probably meant `NodeBT val lt rt`.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's it. Thanks! I wasted too much time on this.

Comment: "incorrect results". -- Boolean Blindness strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

One simplification you might do would be to avoid the separate `TravOrder` type: it's really just a level of indirection in front of the "real" traversal order, which is a function of type `a -> a -> a -> a` that combines the left, right, and val results into a result for the whole node.

```
data BinTree a = EmptyBT |
                 NodeBT a (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
                 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

type TraversalOrder a = a -> a -> a -> a
preOrder, inOrder, postOrder :: Monoid m => TraversalOrder m
preOrder val lt rt = val <> lt <> rt
inOrder val lt rt = lt <> val <> rt
postOrder val lt rt = lt <> rt <> val

collectBT :: Monoid m => TraversalOrder m -> (a -> m) -> BinTree a -> m
collectBT trav f EmptyBT = mempty
collectBT trav f (NodeBT val lt rt) = trav (f val) (collectBT trav f lt) (collectBT trav f rt)
```

You may note that the repetition of `collectBT trav v` is a bit annoying. You can just extract that to a `where` clause if you want (exercise left for the reader), or you can have some fun and write this traversal in terms of the catamorphism for your tree type:

```
cataBT :: b -> (a -> b -> b -> b) -> BinTree a -> b
cataBT fin combine t = case t of
  EmptyBT -> fin
  NodeBT val lt rt -> combine val (go lt) (go rt)
    where go = cataBT fin combine

collectBT :: Monoid m => TraversalOrder m -> (a -> m) -> BinTree a -> m
collectBT trav f = cataBT mempty (trav . f)
```

This `cataBT` handles recursively folding over your tree in any way; `collectBT` is a simple special case that prescribes `mempty` for `EmptyBT`, and calls `f` before delegating to `trav` for combination.